# Brownian semigroup, vague convergence

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

I have a question about a semigroup and vague convergence.

Let $(\mu_{t})_{t>0}$ be a vaguely continous semigroup of measures on $([0,\infty[,\mathcal{B}([0.\infty[))$, i.e.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mu_{t}([0,\infty[)&\leq1&\quad{\rm for\,all}\,t>0\\
\lim_{t \to 0}\mu_{t}&=&\delta_{0}\quad{\rm vaguely}\,(\delta_{0}\,{\rm is \,dirac \,measure })
\end{eqnarray*}

For $f \in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and $t>0$, we define
\begin{eqnarray*}
p_{t}f(x)&=&\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y) \frac{1}{\sqrt[]{2 \pi t}} \exp \left[ \frac{-|x-y|^{2}}{2t} dy\right],\,x\in\mathbb{R}\\
\tilde{p}_{t}f(x)&=&\int_{0}^{\infty}(p_{s}f)(x)\,\mu_{t}(ds),\,x\in\mathbb{R}
\end{eqnarray*}

In this situation, can we get the following assertion?:
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \tilde{p_{t}}f \to f \,{\rm in \,}dx{\rm -measure} \, ({\rm or \,in\,} L^{p}\,(1\leq p<\infty))\cdots(*)
\end{eqnarray*}

e.g. for $f \geq0$, $p=2$

Since
\begin{eqnarray*}
\tilde{p_{t}}f-f &\leq& \int_{0}^{\infty}(p_{s}f)\,\mu_{t}(ds)-f \mu_{t}([0,\infty[)\\
&=& \int_{0}^{\infty}((p_{s}f)-f)\,\mu_{t}(ds)
\end{eqnarray*}
We get (By Schwarz inequality)
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\tilde{p_{t}}f-f|^{2}dx &\leq&  \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |(p_{s}f)-f|^{2}\,dx \, \mu_{t}(ds)
\end{eqnarray*}

By using the famous fact that for $1\leq p<\infty,\,f \in C_{0}^{\infty}(R)$, $p_{t}f\to f$ in $L^{p} $, I think we get $(*)$. How do I use $\lim_{t \to 0}\mu_{t}=\delta_{0}\quad{\rm vaguely}$?